# ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: linux, git, github

The repo was cloned using SSH at the start. I had no issues pushing to Github until today. I've been trying to solve this error for a whole day but i still cannot solve this error.. It would be great if anyone can shed some light on this! Thank you :)

```
2dsnakegame git:(main) git push origin main
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
➜  2dsnakegame git:(main) git remote
origin
➜  2dsnakegame git:(main) git remote --v
origin  git@github.com:xxxx/2dsnakegame.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:xxxx/2dsnakegame.git (push)
```

Comment: `ping github.com`? `ssh git@github.com`?

Comment: both commands gave me the same error message


`ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`

Comment: You have network configuration problem related to neither git nor ssh.

Comment: Happens in WSL for me and the workaround is to use git clone HTTPS links to Github instead of git clone SSH links.

Comment: I have the same issue. I can access my repo from a different computer, but not my notebook which has a working internet connection. I am on WSL2.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same situation working on Windows with WSL2. It looks like there was a trouble on the connection to the DNS server, so I basically reset my TCP/IP with the following commands and then `git pull`/`git push` worked again.

From [University of Wisconsin: Windows 10 TCP/IP Reset](https://kb.wisc.edu/dermatology/page.php?id=31480): Open the `cmd` prompt on Windows as an administrator and run the following commands in this order in order to fix your connection problem:

```sh
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Finally, restart your computer.